# Using Cross tabs in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to use Crystal Reports in generating my report for my ASP.NET website. Unfortunately, it appears like this. It appears properly when exported to other extensions. I have tried tinkering with every thing but it won't display as it is supposed to be. Can anyone settle this one? Thanks very much!!

Screenshot can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNHaC.jpg

Comment: It would help to know how it looks when it looks as it should.